# Express multer upload files with dynamic file name (as numeric order)

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node JS and want to create a server Rest API for images uploading with file name as numeric order (eg. 1, 2, 3, 4).

**server.js**

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (request, file, callback) {
    var newDestination = 'dataset/' + request.body.ktp;
    var stat = null;
    try {
      stat = fs.statSync(newDestination);
    } catch (err) {
      fs.mkdirSync(newDestination);
    }
    if (stat && !stat.isDirectory()) {
      throw new Error('Directory cannot be created because an inode of a different type exists at "' + dest + '"');
    }
    callback(null, newDestination);
  },
  filename(request, file, callback) {
    // const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    callback(null, Date.now() + '.jpg');
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use('/images', express.static('dataset'));

app.post('/registrasi', upload.array('photos'), function (req, res) {
  const { ktp, nama, namaPerusahaan, alamat } = req.body;

  const uploadInfo = req.files.map(file => {
    return {
      sourceName: file.originalname,
      newName: file.filename,
      ktp: ktp,
      nama: nama,
      namaPerusahaan: namaPerusahaan,
      alamat: alamat
    };
  });
  res.send(uploadInfo);
});
```

My problem is I want to create dynamic file name from uploaded images (eg. 1, 2, 3, 4).
If someone know please help me. Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: I want to create dynamic file name from uploaded images (eg. 1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: You can set one variable like req.fileCount = 0 and increament each time

Comment: @Sagar how to do so ?

Comment: @Lordrauf does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Following.

```
if(!req.headers.index)
   req.headers.index=0
var filename = (req.headers.index++) + path.extname(file.originalname)
```

Comment: @Lordrauf Great !!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage to achieve this requirement -

Actually I am uploading my file/image to AWS S3 bucket. So I was needed to dynamic the bucket_path and file_name like:

- MAIN_BUCKET/[SUB_FOLDER]/[fileName].file_extention

For this, I simply receiving the static fileName i.e.; 'file'.

```
 app.use('/file-upload', upload.array('file', 1), fileUploadRoutes);
```

now I was needed to dynamic my file path, even file name. so I set the header on my frontend and call the API with same headers. Headers be like:

```
headers: [{name: 'fileName', value: [fileNameIwantToUpload]]
```

On Backend, I accept the header and set the bucket path in upload function called above as a middleware where route is mentioned:

```
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      acl: 'public-read',
      s3,
      bucket: (req, file, cb) => {
        /*I'm using req.get('fileName') to get the dynamic file path from frontend */
        const bucketName = 'veiggybro/'+ req.get('fileName');
        cb(null, bucketName)
      },
      key: function(req, file, cb) {
      /* Same i did here for setting the dynamic path */
        req.file = process.env.AWS_FILE_PATH + '/' + req.get('fileName')+ '/' + Date.now() + file.originalname;
        cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
      }
   })
});
```

That works for me. Happy Coding.